# What is the new "Navigation drawer" which Google uses?

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer

You can see it, for example, in the Google News app. How is it properly called?

[image]

In documentation I find only old Navigation drawer:

https://material.io/design/components/navigation-drawer.html

Is there a reference or third-party implementation? For example, for the old Navigation drawer there is a popular third-party implementation:

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Comment: Bottom sheet. In the Material Components library, there's `BottomSheetDialog` and `BottomSheetDialogFragment` available, which show a dialog like that. There's also `BottomSheetBehavior`, which you can set on a child of a `CoordinatorLayout` to make it behave similarly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mike M! This is a "Bottom Sheet":

https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/

https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html

[image]